# Access headers in Frisby

Tags: javascript, cookies, automated-tests

I am using the Frisby.js library to test some APIs, and I need to access a session cookie in the set-cookie header to send with following requests.

When I try the inspectJSON() method, I am not seeing the headers contained in the output, and I have not been able to identify any way to get access to the headers in the response.  Any help much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This example chains a Login call with a subsequent call which adds the "set-cookie" to the next call.  The cookie is maintained as a web browser would, and the second call will only work with the set-cookie passed along to the second call.

```
var cookie = "";
frisby.create('Login')
.post('localhost:8080/login', {
    "username": "test_user_01",
    "password": "abcd1234",
}, {
    json: true
})
.inspectJSON()      // Prints response json to stdout
 .inspectHeaders()  // Prints out all the headers in response
.expectStatus(200)  // Check for http success
.expectJSONTypes({  // Check for any reported errors
    status: 1,
    message: 'success'
})
.after(function(body,res) {
    cookie = res.headers['set-cookie'];

    // Fetch account
    frisby.create('Get Accounts')
        .get(utils.URL + '/accounts?includeAllAccounts=1', {
                    headers:  {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Accept": "application/json",
                        "Cookie": cookie,
                    }
                })
        .inspectJSON()
        .expectStatus(200)
        .expectJSONTypes('responseMap.accounts.0', {
            //These tests will fail if the value is null
            accountNumber: String,
        })
        .toss();
}).toss();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, about 2 minutes after posting this question, I found the answer.  I was able to access the headers in the .after() function as follows:

```
.after(function(body,res) {
    //output headers to console
    console.log('************* Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers, null, 4));
})
```